I have Order Blocks and FVG code in Pine Script V5, how to modify the code to detect, the overlapping of Order Block and FVG, when happens?
I have a code shown below to detect and plot Bullish Order Blocks, Bearish Order Blocks, and Fair Value Gap. Now the code is to be modified for detecting and plotting circles whenever Order Blocks and FVG are overlapping every time in the chart. Green Circle plot when Bullish Order Blocks overlapping with FVG and Vice versa with Red Circle plotted
[Bearish OB with FVG]
[Bullish OB with FVG]
I have tried many ways to get this done, but not coming through.
Code:
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Settings
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
length   = input.int(10, 'Swing Lookback', minval = 3)
showBull = input.int(3, 'Show Last Bullish OB', minval = 0)
showBear = input.int(3, 'Show Last Bearish OB', minval = 0)
useBody  = input(false, 'Use Candle Body')

// Style
bullCss      = input.color(color.new(#2157f3, 80), 'Bullish OB', inline = 'bullcss', group = 'Style')
bullBreakCss = input.color(color.new(#ff1100, 80), 'Bullish Break', inline = 'bullcss', group = 'Style')

bearCss      = input.color(color.new(#ff5d00, 80), 'Bearish OB', inline = 'bearcss', group = 'Style')
bearBreakCss = input.color(color.new(#0cb51a, 80), 'Bearish Break', inline = 'bearcss', group = 'Style')

showLabels = input(false, 'Show Historical Polarity Changes')

// Entry style
entryLabelColor = input.color(color.white, "Entry Label Color")
shortEntryColor = input.color(color.red, "Short Entry Color")
longEntryColor = input.color(color.green, "Long Entry Color")

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// UDT's
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var float bullishObTop = na
var float bullishObBottom = na
var int bullishObTime = na
var bool bullishBreaker = false
var int bullishBreakerTime = na

var float bearishObTop = na
var float bearishObBottom = na
var int bearishObTime = na
var bool bearishBreaker = false
var int bearishBreakerTime = na

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
swings(len) =>
    var os = 0
    var float top = na
    var float bottom = na
    var int topIndex = na
    var int bottomIndex = na

    upper = ta.highest(len)
    lower = ta.lowest(len)

    os := high[len] > upper ? 0 : low[len] < lower ? 1 : os

    if os == 0 and os[1] != 0
        top := high[len]
        topIndex := bar_index[len]

    if os == 1 and os[1] != 1
        bottom := low[len]
        bottomIndex := bar_index[len]

    [top, topIndex, bottom, bottomIndex]

notransp(css) => color.rgb(color.r(css), color.g(css), color.b(css))

display(loc, top, bottom, breaker, breakerTime, css, breakCss) =>
    if breaker
        box.new(loc, top, breakerTime, bottom, notransp(css)
          , bgcolor = css
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time)

         box.new(breakerTime, top, time+1, bottom, na
          , bgcolor = breakCss
          , extend = extend.right
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    
        line.new(loc, top, breakerTime, top, xloc.bar_time, color = notransp(css))
        line.new(loc, bottom, breakerTime, bottom, xloc.bar_time, color = notransp(css))
        line.new(breakerTime, top, time+1, top, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, notransp(breakCss), line.style_dashed)
        line.new(breakerTime, bottom, time+1, bottom, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, notransp(breakCss), line.style_dashed)
    else
        box.new(loc, top, time, bottom, na
          , bgcolor = css
          , extend = extend.right
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    
        line.new(loc, top, time, top, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, notransp(css))
        line.new(loc, bottom, time, bottom, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, notransp(css))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Detect Swings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[top, topIndex, bottom, bottomIndex] = swings(length)
max = useBody ? math.max(close, open) : high
min = useBody ? math.min(close, open) : low

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Bullish OB
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if not na(top) and close > top
    minima = max[1]
    maxima = min[1]
    loc = time[1]

    for i = 1 to length-1
        minima := math.min(min[i], minima)
        maxima := minima == min[i] ? max[i] : maxima
        loc := minima == min[i] ? time[i] : loc

    bullishObTop := maxima
    bullishObBottom := minima
    bullishObTime := loc
    bullishBreaker := false
    bullishBreakerTime := na

if not na(bullishObTop)
    if close < bullishObBottom and not bullishBreaker
        bullishBreaker := true
        bullishBreakerTime := time

    if close > bullishObTop
        bullishObTop := na
        bullishObBottom := na
        bullishObTime := na
        bullishBreaker := false
        bullishBreakerTime := na

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Bearish OB
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if not na(bottom) and close < bottom
    minima = min[1]
    maxima = max[1]
    loc = time[1]

    for i = 1 to length-1
        maxima := math.max(max[i], maxima)
        minima := maxima == max[i] ? min[i] : minima
        loc := maxima == max[i] ? time[i] : loc

    bearishObTop := maxima
    bearishObBottom := minima
    bearishObTime := loc
    bearishBreaker := false
    bearishBreakerTime := na

if not na(bearishObTop)
    if close > bearishObTop and not bearishBreaker
        bearishBreaker := true
        bearishBreakerTime := time

    if close < bearishObBottom
        bearishObTop := na
        bearishObBottom := na
        bearishObTime := na
        bearishBreaker := false
        bearishBreakerTime := na

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Check for OB and FVG overlap
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
fvg_found = false
for i = 1 to length - 1
    if (math.min(close[i], open[i]) < high[i+1] and math.max(close[i], open[i]) > low[i+1])
        fvg_found := true
        break

// Detect Long and Short Entries
if fvg_found
    if not na(bearishObBottom) and close < bearishObBottom
        label.new(bar_index, low, 'Short Entry', color=entryLabelColor, textcolor=shortEntryColor, style=label.style_circle, size=size.small)
    if not na(bullishObTop) and close > bullishObTop
        label.new(bar_index, high, 'Long Entry', color=entryLabelColor, textcolor=longEntryColor, style=label.style_circle, size=size.small)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set Order Blocks
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
for bx in box.all
    bx.delete()

for l in line.all
    l.delete()

if barstate.islast
    // Bullish
    if showBull > 0 and not na(bullishObTop)
        display(bullishObTime, bullishObTop, bullishObBottom, bullishBreaker, bullishBreakerTime, bullCss, bullBreakCss)

    // Bearish
    if showBear > 0 and not na(bearishObTop)
        display(bearishObTime, bearishObTop, bearishObBottom, bearishBreaker, bearishBreakerTime, bearCss, bearBreakCss)

// Debugging labels
if not na(bullishObTop)
    label.new(bullishObTime, bullishObTop, 'Bullish OB', color=color.white, textcolor=color.green)
if not na(bearishObTop)
    label.new(bearishObTime, bearishObTop, 'Bearish OB', color=color.white, textcolor=color.red)

